# Python 3.4 - queue.clear() doesn't works

Tags: python, queue, pyserial, modem

I have a problem with my queue in python. I try receive data from RESET button in Modem. hexadecimal valueas are good, but when i click Reset button again and again, queue didnt clear, but i used command queue.clear().

```
   def receiveData():
        global ser
        global q
        while(True):
            if(ser.isOpen() == True):
                if(ser.inWaiting()):
                    s = ser.read()
                    for i in s:
                        q.put(i)
                    while not q.empty():
                        print(hex(q.get()))
                        q.queue.clear()
```

Output:

```
0x3f
0x9
0x6 
itd itd.
```

Next Click

```
0x3f0x9

0x60x2
```

And My question is: What Can i do for receive data as same as first click when i do it again?

BestGards

Comment: What is your actual question? Please see [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Edited: What Can i do for receive data as same as first click when i do it again?

Comment: What is `ser` and what is `q`? I think you will need to provide more context.

Comment: q = queue.Queue()
ser = serial.Serial(wybranyPort, 57600, timeout=0,
                            parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, rtscts=1)